# Comment system sorting madness

Tags: php, database, mysql

I have a website in which I'm loading all of the users' comments by the number of likes they have. This has caused me some troubles.

Let's say comment #1 has 5 likes, comment #2 has 2 likes, and the rest have 0 likes. We have the following comment id's:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
```

Now let's assume someone else "likes" comment #4. Now the id's ordered are:

```
1   2   4   3   5   6   7   8   9   10
```

Let's assume I'm loading 3 comments at the same time. At scenario #1, I loaded comments:

```
{1, 2, 3}
```

Now when I click "load more," I load:

```
{3, 5, 6}
```

Loaded #3 twice! And comment #4 is never viewed. Problems also happen when a comment is deleted, but that's for later.

How can I work around that? I saw websites that order by "likes" or something similar and I almost never encounter duplicates and/or missing comments. Any tips?

Thanks.

Comment: Stack Exchange does it by always maintaining the same order (perhaps by comment id), but hiding lower-ranked comments.  You can show the hidden comments by clicking "load more," but the order of the original comments is always maintained.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm a little confused on what you mean by `hiding lower-ranked comments`. If they order it by comment id, how are the answers ordered by votes?

Comment: They're not ordered by votes.  That's my whole point.  Why would you order them by votes, when comments are always read in posted order?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Oh I thought they were. Anyway, that's not really what I need, then.

Comment: You're having this problem because you're ordering by likes.  The way to solve it is by *not ordering by likes.*  I've given you a way to do that, and still limit the number of comments shown.  I don't know what to tell you about the duplication (since you haven't shown us any code), but if you fix your ordering, the duplication problem will probably solve itself.

Comment: @RobertHarvey My website has an "order by" and you can choose by "newest," "oldest," and "top." I already have "newest"/"oldest" working perfectly, now the "top" is causing me troubles. I may remove it but, until then, I want to hear if people who implemented similar systems have any tips for me.

Comment: Can you give an example of a site that actually does this?

Comment: @WinstonEwert On reddit you can sort by "top."

Comment: @WinstonEwert [Disqus comments](http://disqus.com/)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're using naive "LIMIT 3" and then "LIMIT 3,3" to return only those additional records required.  Doing so will, quite obviously, result in duplicates and missed comments if a "like" is recorded intra-session.

To resolve that issue, you may want to try one of the following approaches:

- Rather than the `OFFSET` clause, send a `JSON` array of all comment ID's already shown to the user, and exclude them from the viable options via a `WHERE IN(1,2,3)` clause.
- As above, but store the array of comment ID's shown server-side, in the user's current session or even a MySQL temporary table.
- Don't send the entire "new comments" in a single request.  Instead,  have the page request an index of comment ID's and their sortable attributes, and then ask for "comment text" or "comment changes" via distinct requests.
- Don't omit any comment from the list sent to the client.  Instead, include ALL comments in each request, and descide which ones to show client-side.

Be aware that none of the above are without potential performance issues, but one of the approaches will be required if you want to sort by any mutable property, "Likes" or what have you.

Comment: For `WHERE IN()`, isn't there a limit on the number of values I can have inside? Also, wouldn't it be *awfully* slow/bandwidth-consuming (along with storing a JSON of the loaded comments)?

Comment: IN likely has an upper limit, but you can work around that by, if necessary, using a second IN clause.

Comment: And you don't need to send the entire comment in a "skip these" JSON; you can just send a single array of id's